# How can I add class for div .form-item?

Tags: theming, forms

I am using Drupal 7 and I need to change classes for ALL input textfield wrappers (class='form-item'). 
How can I do this without JS? please help

I could change form's, form-submit's and submit-wrapper's (form-actions) classes with this code in template.php:

```
    function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('my_class', 'my_own_class')); 
    }
```

but I cant do anything with textfields and their wrappers

Comment: By looping over all `$form` items and checking if their `#type` is of `textfield`, you should be able to achieve this in your alter hook: `foreach ($form as $key => $element) { if ($element['#type'] == 'textarea') { $form[$key]['#attributes'][] = 'my-attr'; } }`

Answer (score 1):

You can override the output of theme_form_element() function in your theme's template.php file. Just copy the function from includes/form.inc file and put it in template.php as MYTHEME_form_element(), and you can now change classes for only text fields with something like this before initializing $output variable :

```
if($element['#type'] == 'textfield'){
  // Add a class specific to textfields
  $attributes['class'][] = 'custom-textfield-class';
}
```

This code is not tested, but it should work. You should clear drupal cache after implementing the function in template.php.